# Replacement for iPod.app on old iPhone 3G with large buttons for play/pause and prev/next track

Tags: ios, iphone, ipod.app

I've dedicated my old iPhone 3G as a Bluetooth audio player.  It works great except for controlling the audio.  I find that the previous and next buttons are too close to the play/pause button on both the lock screen and in iTunes.  I often jump to the next song when I just wanted to pause the current song.

Are there any iOS 4.2.1 apps out there to fit my needs?  I found [Big Button Music Player](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/big-button-music-player/id354903233?mt=8), which is the type of thing I'm looking for, but the current version requires iOS 5 or greater.

Any recommendations for apps to play the music I already have on my phone, and provide a UI with larger buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Track 8](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/track-8/id519363162) - swipe to change tracks - but I'm not sure whether it is iOS 5 or later.

Comment: It works on iOS 5, too.

Comment: OP is looking for a iOS 4.2.1 solution, Track 8 requires iOS 5.

Comment: @patrix hence why I said 'not sure whether it is iOS 5 or later'

Comment: Compatibility info is available in the App Store. Feel free to edit your question to include additional information.